# Awful FPS in games with GTX 1070

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, opengl, mesa

I recently updated my card to a gtx 1070 because my AMD one was failing on Ubuntu. However some weird things have been happening with it.

I installed the nvidia-378 i think from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa and was shocked at only about 60-120 fps. My GLX version is 1.4 and my OpenGL is either 4.3 or 4.50. My Details tab says I'm running 'GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2'

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

The other weird occurences were that the card fans randomly went to 100% when i was doing nothing intensive and the grub loads very slowly (it sort of phases in from the bottom of the screen to the top)

Many thanks.

Comment: 60-120 FPS is bad? I'm pretty sure your OpenGL version is not 1.4. Pretty much nothing would even work if that were true. However, that is a testing PPA. If you want something more stable, I think you want nvidia-375.

Comment: @dobey I ran glxinfo | grep and it says the OpenGL is 1.4. I am dubious though, as some steam games dont run on 1.4 but they all run. And yes, compared to 250+ on windows, 60-120 is bad

Comment: Please include the output where you got that value for the OpenGL version. What monitor do you have?

Comment: @dobey Okay, i made an error. my opengl shading and profile is all either 4.50 or 4.3.0. My GLX is 1.4 - is that an issue?

Comment: @dobey I have an AOC and a BenQ - dont know specifics. 1920p but fairly low Hz - about 60. i know this means a high fps will mean nothing but all i want to do is keep it off the 60 mark since my frames start to tear then.

Comment: No, the OpenGL version is not the issue.

Comment: @dobey No. This is weird though: have you any other suggestions?

Comment: Contact NVidia support perhaps?  Or follow the instructions in the PPA description: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa